# Import OBJ-C variable inside C class

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode, nuance

i have an issue that i can't resolve.
I have to use a variable declared in objective C file header, in my .c class.
To do this i use this code in my .c file:

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
   #import "RilieviTableViewController.h"
#endif
```

But when i try to use the object, xcode says me "use of undeclared identifier semBtnPressed".
In my obj C header file i declared that object in this way:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#include <AudioToolBox/AudioToolBox.h>
#include "starrec_pal_sema.h"

static id refToSelf;
static StarRec_PAL_Sema *semBtnPressed; // <-- variable i want to import.


@interface RilieviTableViewController : UITableViewController
// other variable that i don't have to import.
@end
```

This project use Nuance libraries and that object is a Nuance object. In the sample they simply import class in ifdef block, but in my case it doesn't work.
Can everyone have a solution?

Comment: Nothing about C.

Comment: purec look At the title before talk.

Comment: Is `__OBJC__` defined when compiling your C file?

Comment: @Willeke in what way i define it? Maybe i do it without know what i'm doing

Comment: See [__OBJC__ in objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054669/objc-in-objective-c)

Comment: ok @willeke i defined it, i think the problem is that the compiler isn't correctly set for objC and c interactions, it is possible?